# If-else conditions not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, textbox, nan

I wrote this code, but only the first condition is working:

```
if(document.getElementById('v').value == Infinity) {
    //alert
}
else if(document.getElementById('v').value == -Infinity) {
    //alert
}       
else if(document.getElementById('v').value == undefined) {
    //alert
} 
else if(document.getElementById('v').value == isNaN) {
    //alert
}
```

Why don't the other conditions (`-Infinity`,`undefined`,`isNaN`) work?

Comment: How can you input infinity?

Comment: @elclanrs well 'Infinity' == Infinity is true because there is coercion happening

Comment: If that's OP's use case, it looks confusing, you'd compare to a string.

Comment: @Numbers, I'm not sure who exactly approved your edit, but it is *not* appropriate for you to change the content of other users posts so radically. Please be careful with your edits in future. Edits are *not* there so that users can edit posts to suit them. As such, I have rolled back your edit.

Comment: Thank you @Sheridan for explaining. I disagree with you, though, because my edit did preserve the meaning of the question entirely, simply changing the way of asking it in a more readable and appropriate way (not certainly to suit my taste).
The title, additionally, is quite wrong as it is right now, as it is misleading. Moreover, the added tags were useful.
I think that an edit that improves a question without changing its meaning, as mine was, should be kept. I don't see the big change you're talking about except for the number of lines I edited, which certainly can' be a valid criterion.

Comment: @Numbers, I'm always suspicious when I see that a title has been changed so radically and extra tags have been added, but to be fair to you and after looking at the edit again in detail, it seems that my rollback *may* have been in haste. The original title was indeed a poor match for that question. I apologise for that, but unfortunately, I am not able to undo a rollback... please feel free to re-edit the post. You should be able to see your original edit from here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21902317/revisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can throw new [exceptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) in Javascript with the [throw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) keyword (see the example below).

> isNaN is a function
>
> To check the validity of a number use: `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` or `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY`

In other words:

```
if (typeof document.getElementById('v') === 'undefined' ||
    document.getElementById('v').length === 0)
  throw new TypeError("Undefined value");
else if(parseInt(document.getElementById('v').value, 10) == Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY)
  throw new RangeError("Value is too big");
else if(isNaN(document.getElementById('v').value))
  throw new TypeError("Value must be a valid number");
```

You can fetch theses Exceptions like:

```
try {
 // call your checkup function here
} catch (exception) {
 alert ("Oh bad... Exception detected: " + exception);
}
```

Comment: great! Now function :)